# How do I print IST in log file using log4j2?

Tags: java, docker, logging, log4j2

I want to print IST in my log file using log4j2. Currently it is printing time in UTC. Below is my log4j2.properties file.

```
name = log4j2

appenders = console, file

appender.file.type = File
appender.file.name = LOGFILE
appender.file.fileName=/home/dockerdev/code/stmtParser/log/fcu_analyzer.log
appender.file.layout.type=PatternLayout
appender.file.layout.pattern=[%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n

appender.console.type = Console
appender.console.name = STDOUT
appender.console.layout.type = EnhancedPatternLayout
appender.console.layout.pattern = %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}{IST} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

loggers=file
logger.file.name=/home/dockerdev/code/stmtParser/log4j2.properties
logger.file.level = info
logger.file.appenderRefs = file
logger.file.appenderRef.file.ref = LOGFILE

rootLogger.level = debug
rootLogger.appenderRefs = file ,stdout
rootLogger.appenderRef.file.ref = LOGFILE
rootLogger.appenderRef.console.ref = STDOUT
```

This I am trying to run in local docker. Log generated from this shows UTC. How can i get IST ? what change is required?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution, since i was using log4j2 I had to only add {IST} after date pattern for file appender. So final properties file which would print IST in log file is

```
appender.file.type = File
appender.file.name = LOGFILE
appender.file.fileName=/home/dockerdev/code/stmtParser/log/fcu_analyzer.log
appender.file.layout.type=PatternLayout
appender.file.layout.pattern=[%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS}{IST} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n
```

Answer (score 0):

Try change timezone inside your Dockerfile